# How to fix navbar changing classes on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using Bootstrap 4 navbar. The navbar is transparent and when scrolling happens, navbar and logo changes to other class or style.
When website is in mobile mode or lower resolution, the navbar toggler shows up. And because of links being white, I wrote another code to change navbar color to a new color.

I just made a 17 second video to explain my problem: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTfb1HpVotHGZJ6btvIGHfAdzt9WmihC/view?usp=sharing)

Navbar HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-transparent fixed-top" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img id="logo" class="navbar-brand-img" src="img/logo.png" width="165" height="56" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-link1" class="nav-link" href="#">Text1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-link2" class="nav-link" href="#">Text2ما</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-link3" class="nav-link" href="#">Text3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-link4" class="nav-link" href="#">Text4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-link5" class="nav-link" href="#">Text5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="font-number shadow-sm call-button ml-auto">09377327877<i class="fas fa-phone"></i></button>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
.navbar {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  padding: 25px 100px 25px 100px;
}

.scrolled {

  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  background: white !important;
}

.scrolled1 {
  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  background: white !important;
}

.scrolled-nav-link {
  transition: 0.7s;
  padding-right: 30px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #727272 !important;
}

.icon-bar {
  color: white;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white !important;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    margin-top: 4px
}

.scrolled-icon-bar {
  background-color: #1480FD !important;
}
.nav-link {
  font-family: "IRANSansM";
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding-right: 30px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color:white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#logo {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#logo:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```
//Navbar class change on scroll

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
    $('#nav-link1,#nav-link2,#nav-link3,#nav-link4,#nav-link5').toggleClass('scrolled-nav-link', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
    $('.icon-bar').toggleClass('scrolled-icon-bar', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
  });
});

//Logo change on scroll

var initialSrc = "img/logo.png";
var scrollSrc = "img/logo-scrolled.png";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
     var value = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (value > 1)
        $("#logo").attr("src", scrollSrc);
     else
        $("#logo").attr("src", initialSrc);
  });
});

//Navbar-toggler color change in lower resolation

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar-toggler").click(function(){
    if ( $("nav").hasClass("scrolled") ) {
    }
    else {
      $("nav").toggleClass("scrolled1");
      $('#nav-link1,#nav-link2,#nav-link3,#nav-link4,#nav-link5').toggleClass('scrolled-nav-link');
      $('.icon-bar').toggleClass('scrolled-icon-bar');

    }
  });
});
```

The problem is, when its in mobile mode and navbar toggler is open, when i scroll down, everything gets messed up, links gets white and other... .
And when i get back to the top of website and close it, other problems show up.

How can i fixed this problems?

Comment: How am i suppose to explain my problem so people can anwser?

Comment: Im still waiting. If there is a problem in my question, Just ask

Comment: i think your elements get messed up in mobile view as you have made your page fixed sized. you should make your page responsive for the small device also. in bootstrap you can use class col-md for medium size devices and col-sm for small size devices.for more info you should google it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-transparent fixed-top"`

to

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-transparent sticky-top"`